# Do TIE Fighter squadrons have names like X-Wing squadrons?

Tags: star-wars, names

In *A New Hope*, the X-Wing squadron attacking the Death Star is called "Red Squadron". Do TIE Fighters have squadron names too? If so, what are they named after (color, alphabet, number)?

Answers from the non-canon Expanded Universe are acceptable.

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Imperial_starfighter_squadrons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several naming conventions...

1. *X-Wing Rogue Squadron* EU works had ***numeric designations*** for them (basically, similar to USAF). Example: [233rd](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/233rd) , [128th TIE Interceptor Squadron](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/128th_TIE_Interceptor_Squadron). And we can't forget Baron Fel's Squints, aka [181st Imperial Fighter Wing](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/181st_Imperial_Fighter_Wing)

   *Essential Guide* series supported this convention, as did *Star Wars Insider* posts.
2. *TIE Fighter* flight simulator game from LucasArts had ***Greek lettered squadrons***:

   [Beta Squadron](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Beta_Squadron), [Mu group](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mu_group) (there was also Mu squadron, to confuse the matters).

   - This convention is now **fully Disney canon**, since there was a [Delta](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Delta_Squadron_%28Lothal%29) squadron on *SW: Rebels*
   - Just to complicate things a bit, some Z-something-named splinter group in TIE Fighter game that names their squadrons Z-Greek- convention, e.g. [Z-Tau Squadron](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Z-Tau_Squadron).
3. Just like Rebels having special squadrons (Rogue), some Imperial squadrons had their own ***special designation***. Such as:

   [Wraith](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Wraith_Squadron_%28Empire%29) from *The Force Unleashed* game, [Bantha training squad](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bantha_Squad) and [Veerpal](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Veerpal_Squadron) and [eminently cool "Fate's Judges"](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Fate's_Judges) from RPGs, and "[Twilight](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Twilight_Squadron_%28Imperial%29)" squadron from <strike>the fraction of sparkling Vampires</strike> *Empire* comics.

   TIE Fighter series games had elite [Eagle Squadron](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Eagle_Squadron) as well as even cooler [Avenger Squadron](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Avenger_Squadron). I'm still awaiting confirmation what level of canon X-Men squadron is.
4. And, just like Rebels, there were ***color themed*** squadrons. Some RPGs used numbers, but some used colors, e.g. [Yellow squadron](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Yellow_Squadron_%28Imperial%29)

   EU/Legends canon calls Darth Vader's "can't shoot a couple of rebels to save Death Star, suckers" squadron "[Black Squadron](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Black_Squadron)" but IIRC that name never made it into Disney canon.

   This convention **also made it into New Disney canon**, with the Admiral Rae's [Sapphire Squadron](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sapphire_Squadron) from *Rise of the Empire*.
5. Evoking Wing Commander series Broadswords, Rapiers etc..., some squadrons were named after **Melee weapons**:

   [Saber](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Saber_Squadron_%28Imperial%29), [Dagger Flight](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dagger_Flight) and [Cutlass](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Cutlass_Squadron) as well as generic [Blade Flight](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Blade_Flight) show that the spirit of Wing Commander is alive and well. Second Death Star had a [Scythe squadron](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Scythe_Squadron), because nothing beats an agricultural implement in a sturdy farmboy's hands.

   EU also has both [Scimitar squadron](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Scimitar_Squadron_%28Imperial%29) from trading card game, not to be confused with even more confusing [Scimitar Flight](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Scimitar_Flight) (which to confuse matters more, was part of  77th Air Wing's Sword Squadron. You're welcome) from Star Wars Insider article.
6. Some names were cool yet **functional**

   Grand Admiral Thrawn had a [Cloak squadron](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Cloak_Squadron), because <strike>he was a fan of Deathly Hallows like Dumbledore</strike> they were using cloaking technology <strike>in violation of Khitomir accords</strike>.

   [Emperor's Shield](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Emperor's_Shield) was a Thrawn-trained squadron that protected the Emperor on Second Death Star arrival, while [Emperor's Sword](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Emperor's_Sword) was Emperor's Praetorian Guard with wings.

As Richard's comment noted, a very good list of known Imperial squadrons can be found on [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Imperial_starfighter_squadrons).

Comment: #6 was the best part.